# SELECT rows with minimum count(*)

Tags: mysql

Let's say i have a simple table voting with columns

```
id(primaryKey),token(int),candidate(int),rank(int).
```

I want to extract all rows having specific rank,grouped by candidate and most importantly only with minimum count(*).
So far i have reached

```
SELECT candidate, count( * ) AS count
FROM voting
WHERE rank =1
AND candidate <200
GROUP BY candidate
HAVING count = min( count )
```

But,it is returning empty set.If i replace min(count) with actual minimum value it works properly.
I have also tried

```
SELECT candidate,min(count)
FROM (SELECT candidate,count(*) AS count
      FROM voting
      where rank = 1
      AND candidate < 200
      group by candidate
      order by count(*)
      ) AS temp
```

But this resulted in only 1 row,I have 3 rows with same min count but with different candidates.I want all these 3 rows.

Can anyone help me.The no.of rows with same minimum count(*) value will also help.

Sample is quite a big,so i am showing some dummy values

```
1 $sampleToken1 101 1

2 $sampleToken2 102 1

3 $sampleToken3 103 1

4 $sampleToken4 102 1
```

Here ,when grouped  according to candidate there are 3 rows combining with count( * ) results

```
candidate count( * )

101              1

103              1

102              2
```

I want the top 2 rows to be showed i.e with count(*) = 1 or whatever is the minimum

Comment: Please show some sample input data and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this script as pattern -

```
-- find minimum count
SELECT MIN(cnt) INTO @min FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM voting GROUP BY candidate) t;

-- show records with minimum count
SELECT * FROM voting t1
  JOIN (SELECT id FROM voting GROUP BY candidate HAVING COUNT(*) = @min) t2
    ON t1.candidate = t2.candidate;
```

Comment: Thanks...I am able to do it now by @min variable.(I was not knowing we can create these types of variables lasting multiple queries in mysql)
PS-I don't think there is any need to use JOIN in second query of yours,it isn't grouping by candidates either

Answer (score 0):

Remove your HAVING keyword completely, it is not correctly written.

and add SUB SELECT into the where clause to fit that criteria.

(ie.  select cand, count(*) as count from voting where rank = 1 and count = (select ..... )

Comment: It's showing "Unknown column count in where clause" when i am using SUB SELECT

Answer (score 0):

The HAVING keyword can not use the MIN function in the way you are trying. Replace the MIN function with an absolute value such as `HAVING count > 10`

Comment: That's what i don't want.I don't know the absolute value.I just know it's minimum

Comment: Minimum of what? Can you get that value first, then apply it to the HAVING keyword?

Comment: minimum of count(*) when grouped by candidate.Yeah @Devart has just suggested the same thing.I wasn't knowing earlier how to store variables in-between queries

Comment: Yea, his solution looks like the best for this scenario