# Convert this subquery into a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, count, subquery

Does anyone know if it's possible to convert this subquery into a JOIN?

```
SELECT DISTINCT

lastname,
c.fullname,

(SELECT COUNT(lg.action) FROM tbl_log AS lg WHERE lg.userid = u.id AND lg.course = c.id) AS 'Total Course Hits Per Student'

FROM tbl_user AS u    
JOIN tbl_user_enrolments AS ents ON ents.userid = u.id    
JOIN tbl_enrol AS en ON ents.enrolid = en.id    
JOIN tbl_course AS C ON c.id = en.courseid    
JOIN tbl_context AS ctx ON c.id = ctx.instanceid    
JOIN tbl_role_assignments AS ra ON ra.contextid = ctx.id AND ra.userid = u.id       

LOG TABLE     

+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |  
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| id          |                     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |  
| time        |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| userid      |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| course      |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| action      |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  

USER Table

+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |  
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| id           |                     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |  
| username     |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| userpassword |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| lastname     |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| firstname    |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  

COURSE table

+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |  
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+  
| id           |                     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |  
| category     |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| fullname     |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |  
| shortname    |                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |   
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I link the users together via the enrolment and context tables.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you take a query on the log_table

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(tbl_log.action)
    lastname,
    c.fullname,
FROM tbl_log
JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_log.userid = tbl_user.id
JOIN tbl_course ON tbl_log.course = tbl_course.id
GROUP BY tbl_log.userid, tbl_log.course
```

I don't know if you need the other tables? This would provide a count, the student name and the course name if I am not mistaken. However, you only get the actual logs, so no occurences for students that haven't done anything.

Otherwise an OUTER JOIN may suffice on the log-table. I have no time to check now in SQL fiddle. Hope this already helps you a bit on your way.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'd like to identify student actions even if users have not performed any actions (zero). Ultimately, I'd like to take a count of the lowest action number per course, even if this is zero. Hopefullying reading, course, lowest action count.

Comment: Hi @luckylwk, your MySQL looks good and answers my initial question. I've been vague in my first question, if there are 20 people on a course, I'm trying to find the student with the lowest usage. The next step is to count the lowest usage of any student on the course: `code` SELECT u.lastname, c.fullname, MIN(COUNT(lg.action)) FROM tbl_log AS lg JOIN tbl_user AS u ON lg.userid = u.id JOIN tbl_course AS c ON lg.course = c.id GROUP BY lg.course, lg.userid `code` but my MIN() function won't work. I have an invalid use of group function.

Comment: That one will not work because the MIN function will return one row, not a bool of which is the MIN one. You can ORDER BY COUNT(lg.action) ASC which will put the minimum count in the first row.

Comment: Thanks again @luckylwk. I'm experiencing that problem. I want 1 row per course (lowest value per course) but in other experiments, I have just one row per everything. I'm after for example course, lowest usage (number), repeated by course, lowest number. Is there a way I can acheive this without a subquery? I've managed to make a subquery do this but then get stuck in adding it to a much larger query.

Comment: Thanks luckylwk. This is almost what I'm after. The only problem I have is that each record in the mdl_log table is an action. Therefore, this counted all actions per course. Of the say, 20 users on the course, I'm trying to find the lowest amount of actions. This is why I've been using the count. I've been trying to wrap it up as follows: [Stack overflow minimum count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671630/select-rows-with-minimum-count) but have had no luck.

Comment: You are not very specific (which you need to be with queries). What do you mean with lowest number of actions? Lowest per what criteria? See:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a249f/11 / This gives you a row per course for each individual user that was active.